# What does "RP" mean in the context?

Tags: abbreviations

Can you help me understand what my client meant about ***RP*** in this context:

> I canceled my application since the payment scheme wasn't validated
>   in RP.

Comment: What does *doe's* mean? And honestly, this is not an English-language question at all. Just because there is something written in English that somebody else does not understand does not make it a suitable question for ELU. I can pull out a numberless infinitude of things scrawled in scientific journals and written on the subway walls that I fail to understand. That doesn't make them English matters.

Comment: It's presumably some form of certification of your payment scheme which applies in whatever country you or your client makes / receives payment.

Comment: I'm afraid that @tchrist is correct. The answer to your actual question is, "No, we can't help you understand what your client meant. What you should do is hire someone who understands English as it is written by your client."

Comment: Obviously it refers to *[Received Pronunciation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation)* (“Received Pronunciation (RP) is the standard accent of Standard English in England...”); ie the person is saying that the payment scheme was not validated using good English.

Comment: @jwpat7: Maybe. But I think "RP" more likely stands for _roleplaying_, and the application was cancelled because it wasn't validated by an elf or gnome.

Comment: In all seriousness, Pennf0lio, you should just fire an email back to your client, and say, "I'm sorry, I'm not sure I know what you mean by 'RP' – could you please elaborate?" I'm guessing your client won't mind explaining. These sort of faulty assumptions ("Oh, I'm sorry, I just assumed you were familiar with that abbreviation...") are not uncommon in business correspondence.

Comment: RP could stand for the Latin "res publica," meaning all things subject to concern by the citizenry.  Probably not, though.  Back when I was teaching undergraduates, I would usually say at least once a semester:  "Now, if you do not understand a word I use, just ask for clarification."  No one ever did.  Still, I encourage you, as J.R. suggests, to ask your client what s/he meant.

Answer (score 3):

A quick internet search turned up at http://www.abbreviations.com/RP a list of 136 things abbreviated RP.   The second of these is "Indonesian Rupiah", which makes sense if your client is in Indonesia.  If not, then check the remaining 135.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that **RP** isn't really a misspelt, or perhaps scribbled, **AP**, standing for *Accounts Payable* or *Accounts Payable system*?

When I do my crossword tired I frequently write my A's and R's similarly enough to confuse them, by rounding the top of the **A** and the inside corner of the **R**'s tail.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're talking about payment schemes and validation, RP could mean *relying party*. The RP relies on the Certificate Authority in an encrypted transaction using Public Key Infrastructure.

[This isn't mentioned in the 136 expansions at abbreviations.com]